# Searching the mpaa cast file for movies with an actor in them?

Tags: java, eclipse, string, text

Just to clarify- I am not looking for exact answers, just something to get me on the right track.  I am supposed to create a program which will input this [text file](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/45graph/cast.mpaa.txt) and will allow a user to input an actor's name into a scanner and will return all of the movies that that actor has been in.  The only problem is that I know that if the scanner finds the actor's name, then the movie title will have to be the the previous movie- in other words if there is a title of a movie, followed by a list of actors, followed by an indent, and followed by another movie title- then the movie will have to be the first title.  I do not know how to get the scanner to go backwards once it has found the actor's name.  In other words: once the scanner finds the same name that has been inputted by the user, I don't know how to tell it to do the opposite of Scanner.next (the previous word) until it runs into a movie title.  How would I do this?

Comment: Have you considered parsing the file and storing a `List` of (for the sake of argument) `Movie` objects? Perhaps each `Movie` might then contain a `List` of another type, maybe `Actor`(s)?

Comment: Sorry I'm not very versed in this stuff and while I could look it up you seem like you know what you mean- what is a list and how would I create one?

Comment: `List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();` then you'd *add* `Movie` instances... did they not cover this at all in your class?

Comment: They did but if I understood it I guess I wouldn't be here.

Comment: One more thing- in order to add movies to the list, I would need to tell the scanner that a string is only a movie if it is a sequence of words followed by some numbers in parentheses.  How would I tell it to check for this, especially considering I can't know how many words will be in a movie title.  In other words how do I tell the scanner to see if there are any number of words followed by (a number)?

Answer (score 0):

> string is only a movie if it is a sequence of words followed by some numbers in parentheses ... how do I tell the scanner to see if there are any number of words followed by (a number)?

You could use a regular expression. Like,

```
String regex = "^.*\\s*\\(\\d+\\)$";
System.out.println("The Matrix (1999)".matches(regex));
System.out.println("Laurence Fishburne".matches(regex));
```

Output is

```
true
false
```

Comment: The only problem is that I need it to know that what is in the parentheses HAS TO BE a number.  because elsewhere in the file there are words followed by roman numerals in parentheses like word (IV).

Comment: Oh I didnt realize d meant a number.  Thank you so much you have been a huge help.

Comment: How could I make a list that includes all the movies, though?  Like would I have to do it all manually or is there a way to make the code add every movie to the list.  Because the movies are only at the beginning of the lines and before the numbers in parentheses.

Comment: I think what's confusing me is that I know how to get the scanner to import the file, but I don't know how to allow it to do the following:
   Return an arraylist of  all the actors for any given movie.
   Return all the movies that contain a certain word in the title.
   Return all movies that have a specific actor.
    Return all the movies released in a certain year.
Return an arraylist of all the actors whose names contain a certain word.